# Fresh desk Language localization not working

Tags: android, kotlin, freshdesk

I implemented fresh desk SDK successfully but when I'm changing language in-app it does not update on the chat screen. it works if I'm changing device language.

Fresh desk: https://support.freshchat.com/support/solutions/articles/50000000207-freshdesk-messaging-android-sdk-integration-steps

I already try Freshchat.notifyAppLocaleChange(activityContext); method as per doc but it's not working

Comment: How are you changing language in app? It might not be feeding through to Freshchat's SDK properly. Try debugging the app's locale when that notify call is made.

Comment: @JakeLee I used updateConfiguration method to change language and it's working for the whole app but it's only not working for Freshdesk SDK

Comment: @JakeLee Can you please help in this?

Comment: @JakeLee I checked my side freshdesk taking system locale not app locale. it should take app locale can you help me in this?